# Does sentience need a minimally complex system

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

May it be that consciousness could possibly [I'm not saying it will ever be actual!] be instantiated in a very at least explicitly simple system.

Take a circuit bent calculator as an example.

Comment: Stephen Wolfram proved that a particular 2-state5-color Turing machine is universal, and he further conjectures that 2-state-3-color one is universal as well. These would surely be simplest candidates.

Comment: How can you know? If a digital computer could be conscious, why couldn't an elevator? After all, elevators "remember" which floor you want to go to. And more to the point: If a sack of meat like me can be conscious ... why couldn't a cell? It's another variation on the Sorites paradox. If you have a penny, you're not rich. If you have two pennies, you're not rich. But if you have a billion pennies, you're rich. At what point do you become rich? At what point does a sack of meat or a digital circuit become conscious?

Answer (score 1):

This question gets to the heart of the issue of philosophy of mind: what is consciousness, and how did it get there? Once we know how consciousness works and how it's produced, we can answer the question if whether complexity is one of the necessary ingredients, so to speak, of consciousness.

In general, we could take two approaches, either a **materialistic** approach or a **dualistic** approach.

A materialistic (or **monist**) approach to the question of consciousness assumes that everything produced or experienced by a conscious mind can be explained by physical phenomena and natural processes. Instead of discussing the many theories on this context, I'd suggest to read what's written in the subject by John Searle and Daniel Dennett (or if your lazy just read the Wikipedia or SEP articles about their theories). As far as I know, anyone who believes that consciousness (or what we describe as consciousness) is a natural outgrowth of the brain's function, also believes that complexity is a necessary, but not sufficient, factor. Personally, I think that the 'complexity' necessary for consciousness isn't a simple matter of quantified how complex a system is, but requires a complexity arising from *variation*, in that there are a variety of different ways in which the brain interacts with the environment which all need to interact with each other (though even a complexity of that type may not sufficient, I believe that it is necessary). To answer your question fully of precisely *what level of complexity*, given a 'complexity quantification' would be theoretically possible but I doubt that, at the present time, anyone has a full enough understanding of consciousness to be able to answer that question.

On the other hand, we have **dualists**, who believe in something aphysical, or metaphysical, which is the producer of consciousness, such as a 'soul'. In theory, or at least in the ancient understanding of a 'soul', since a soul is unrelated to physical phenomena it doesn't necessarily have to belong to a complex system, and an empty cardboard box could be just as conscious as a human. By mentioning a calculator, I imagine that you think that either computational ability or the ability to have an input/output system are minimal requirements for consciousness, but if we're going with the soul idea, even those relationships are artificial ones. (I should note that dualists have argued with me about this idea, but only usually by appealing to external factors, such as the idea that God wouldn't give a soul to inanimate objects)

Probably the most interesting opinion in this context is that of philosopher David Chalmers, who is a dualist in the sense that he believes consciousness to be something other than physical properties, but doesn't believe in the ancient conception of the soul that I've assumed until now. He believes that it is indeed possible that all objects or systems have a form of consciousness, and that their level of self-awareness is in fact a reflection of their complexity. Thus, a minimally complex system (even just a simple circuit) does have a 'consciousness' to it, albeit a 'low-level' or simple one. The more complex a being/system is, the qualitatively more profound is it's feeling of consciousness. I think that he believes, therefore, that the universe itself has a 'great consciousness', as do solar systems, anthills, and the Internet. I'd suggest reading some of his works to understand his opinion better. (I personally find his theory fascinating but patently absurd, so I'll admit that I could be misrepresenting it)